# how to filter by data using BPF

Tags: filtering, wireshark, pcap, tcpdump

I am trying to filter a pcap file using bpf syntax. I need it to return only GET requests from HTTP that contains a certain word in the GET request, is it possible to do it? I managed to get the GET requests from HTTP but I can't find how to filter by the data of the packet.

Comment: By "btf" do you mean BPF?  That's not going to be any kind of fun using BPF.  Is there a reason you can't use a display filter?

Comment: @DavidHoelzer yes I meant BPF, the reason I need it is because I got an assignment to do it using BPF only

Comment: That will be incredibly painful unless you know that the string will always be in the same location.  I'll give an example.

Comment: @DAvidHoelzer I just checked and the string that I am looking for is in the same location all the time, the request looks like this: GET /xxxx/TheStringIamLookingFor/.....

Comment: Then modify what I gave you to look in that location... Still, the proper approach is to account for variable length IP and TCP headers.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've been asked to do is tricky, difficult, and impractical unless Wireshark or TCPDump do not have a protocol parser for some weird protocol that you are using.

A way to grab GET requests using BPF only would be as follows:

```
 dst port 80 and tcp[(tcp[12]>>2):4]=0x47455420
```

The reason it must be done in this way is that you must account for the possibility of changing TCP options and, as a result, changing locations for where the data offset begins.  This figures out where the data starts and examines the first four bytes for the string "GET ".

You may also note that I am taking a shortcut for the TCP data offset value in byte 12.  It would be better practice to do this:

```
 (tcp[12]>>4)*4
```

or this:

```
 (tcp[12]&0xf0 >> 2)
```

This would account for any bits in the reserved lower nibble being enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It is late for an answer but anyway.
You can filter the GET or any other HTTP requests with BPF.
The [next example](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/bpfcc/-/tree/9a55e766cc76b5fab96eb0b631a37315c02f5269/examples/networking/http_filter) from bpfcc-tools shows the similar task implementation. It supposed to works on live network interface, not a pcap file. But I hope you can adopt it to be applied on a file.